# Using SetEnvIf to not log overly accessed URLs

Tags: htaccess, apache, performance, logging

I'm trying to figure out how to craft my SetEnvIf's in my apache config so that the server hard disk isn't spinning 24/7 over log entries.

What I want to do is disable logging for all domains and subdomains the server has DNS records for, however, on the example.com domain, I want it where requests to the root (a.k.a. http://example.com/) not be logged since that's frequently accessed.

This is what I have so far as httpd.conf code but I'm not sure how to modify it to satisfy my criteria above.

```
SetEnvIf Host "^example.com$" nolog
SetEnvIf Request_URI !/ !nolog
SetEnvIf Host "^???$" nolog
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log common env=!nolog
```

Later I may think about no longer logging PHP file access as I don't want potential hackers to flood my log files anymore.

How do I adjust my code to satisfy my requirements?

Comment: Logging is very minimal overhead compared to serving pages.   Logging one line per request does not contribute significantly to server load.     Without logging, you have no idea that an attack is happing and you have no hope of blocking the attackers.  Why would you want to disable logging for requests that are likely to be hacking?

Comment: While it's trivial to set up logging on a per virtual host basis (you don't use setenvif) Stephen is right. The cost of logging is trivial and the benefits are significant.